# immediates (square brackets) and index registers + les with 2x dw in stack segment

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, memory-segmentation

I am very new to assembly, and try to learn it by understanding a disassembly of an old 16-bit dos game (disassembly generated by IDA Free).

There are 2 things I read in that code and I think, guessed what it does. Nevertheless I am not really sure if I'm correct, so I wanted to check (just shortened example code here btw):

**1)**

```
lds di, some_adress ; (eg: ds = 0012h, di=BAF6h afterwards)
xor cx, cx
mov [di], cx ; <- what segment is used here
```

I guess its using the `ds` as some magic default segment, to apply the offset and calculate the physical adress.

**2)**

```
assume ds:dseg (e.g. 0012h)
mov ax, 0BAF6h ; <- why is the leading 0 here btw
push ds
push ax
```

so my stack is looking like:

```
...  ...
02   ds (0012)
00   ax (BAF6)  <- sp
```

then:

```
mox bx, sp
les di, ss:[bx]
```

I guess the registers are now `es`=`0012h` and `di`=`BAF6h`, which would make sense when looking at the rest of the games code, but since my stack is looking like `BAF6 0012 ...`, this would mean that the first word is put into `di` while the second word is put into `es`. This confuses me a bit, since it's kinda reversing the order of the two words (from my point of view).

Comment: You could download the [intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) so you wouldn't have to guess. Regarding byte order, x86 is little endian so lower addresses have the less significant parts. That's why first word is loaded into `di` and second into `es` (note that the words also have their bytes stored in little-endian order).

Comment: sometimes the simplest things just dont come to mind, thank you for this hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ds` is the default segment for all other other 16-bit memory addressing modes except `[bp+immediate]`, `[bp+si+immediate]` and `[bp+di+immediate]`. So basically, unless you use `bp` in indirect addressing, the default segment is `ds`. If you use `bp` in indirect addressing, then the default segment is `ss`.
2. A leading zero in hexadecimal numbers is a convention used by many disassemblers and assembler syntaxes to separate hexadecimal numbers from symbols (some other disassemblers and assemblers use `0x` instead of `0`). Leading zeros do not affect the **numeric** value of any number, and it's the same in all number systems (binary, decimal, hexadecimal, etc.).

Just as you assume, [`les`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/les.html)`di, ss:[bx]` loads the first word into `di` and and the second word into `es`, so it's equivalent to:

```
mov di,ss:[bx]
mov es,ss:[bx+2]
```

Comment: The leading zero is to differentiate numbers from symbols. `BAF6h` would be a symbol name.

Comment: @Jester You're right, of course. I'm so accustomed to `0x` convention used by YASM, NASM, NDISASM and udis86 that I forgot the significance of leading zeros.

Comment: thank u very much for the quick answer and the resources. i was just confused about the zero as it is not always present in the disassembled code. sometimes its just "mov ax, 3D00h" w/o the zero

Comment: @cdx In the case a hexadecimal number begins with a value in the range `0` ... `9`, there is no need to prefix it with `0` to differentiate it from symbols, because symbol names can not begin with `0` ... `9`, but they can begin with `a` ... `f` and `A` ... `F`.